# If i uninstall chinese "SimSun" and "Mingliu" font, what is the default font that it will show?

Tags: html, css

A quick question about fonts. So I have a webpage that uses SimSun and Mingliu Font. I'm wondering what the default font if I delete the SimSun and Mingliu.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? You can use dev tools to "remove" the font.

Comment: @disinfor I have tried it. How do I know the default font after removing it..

Comment: You can look under the "Computed" tab in Chrome and see what font is loaded. Or if you're using Firefox, there is a Fonts tab

Comment: @disinfor Thanks! It shows up as Times New Roman. Doesn't seems right, can Times New romans show Chinese characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If browser detects that there are no fonts that declared in CSS, it will use default fonts.

[Here is an sum up of default web browser fonts](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults/)

Comment: Thanks! It shows up as Times New Roman. Doesn't seems right, can Times New romans show Chinese characters?

Comment: Yeah, it can show Chinese characters according [this accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/211378/how-to-display-chinese-characters-on-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no font set, the browser will default to serif font-family as the default font, and depending on your OS it will resolve to either time or times new roman.